# How can I access the images in an Instagram JSON? Use objects or an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Since I stumbled over some wrong solutions (at least always pointing into the right direction) for having your instagram photos pulled onto my site, I started looking for new ways. And I had to implement SSL into the cURL scripting part to get the instagram feed.

However I am stuck in the following part: How can I tell my script to show my images?

I found out, that `$result->data` works, but if I continue this line with `->images` PHP         gives me the `"Trying to get property of non-object"`. And the output of the decoded JSON is still lacking overviewability. I pasted here the code as far as I am right now, debugging mode.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/myUserID/media/recent/?access_token=myAccessToken');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$result=json_decode($result);
$data=($result->data);
var_dump ($data->images);

// echo "<img src="$result->images->thumbnail->url">"
?>
```

Here is the output of the `json_decode`:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (15) { 
        ["attribution"]=> NULL 
        ["tags"]=> array(4) {         
            [0]=> string(5) "remix" 
            [1]=> string(9) "trncfrmcn" 
            [2]=> string(4) "tygn" 
            [3]=> string(9) "mastering" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> string(5) "image" 
        ["location"]=> NULL 
        ["comments"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
            ["count"]=> int(0) 
            ["data"]=> array(0) { } 
        } 
        ["filter"]=> string(7) "Toaster" 
        ["created_time"]=> string(10) "1373149059" 
        ["link"]=> string(34) "http://instagram.com/p/bcOOGMF5Vi/" 
        ["likes"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { 
            ["count"]=> int(6) 
            ["data"]=> array(4) { 
                [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) { 
                    ["username"]=> string(13) "itsallaboutva" 
                    ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) 
"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_186336970_75sq_1341852049.jpg" 
                    ["id"]=> string(9) "186336970" 
                    ["full_name"]=> string(16) "Victoria Anwuzia" 
                 } 
                 [1]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) { 
                     ["username"]=> string(15) "eatmybeatsordie" 
                     ["profile_picture"]=> string(76) 
"http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_32709002_75sq_1355602472.jpg" 
                     ["id"]=> string(8) "32709002" 
                     ["full_name"]=> string(12) "D-Mite Beats" 
                 } 
                 [2]=> object(stdClass)#9 (4) { 
                     ["username"]=> string(12) "joetranmusic" 
                     ["profile_picture"]=> string(76) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_32545994_75sq_1362449260.jpg" 
                     ["id"]=> string(8) "32545994" 
                     ["full_name"]=> string(8) "Joe Tran" 
                 } 
                 [3]=> object(stdClass)#10 (4) { 
                     ["username"]=> string(14) "xariahmarshall" 
                     ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_275171230_75sq_1362937374.jpg" 
                     ["id"]=> string(9) "275171230" 
                     ["full_name"]=> string(14) "xariahmarshall" 
                  } 
              } 
          } 
          ["images"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (3) { 
              ["low_resolution"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (3) { 
                  ["url"]=> string(79) "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/ded954f8e68911e2adc122000a1f9ace_6.jpg" 
                  ["width"]=> int(306) 
                  ["height"]=> int(306) 
              } 
              ["thumbnail"]=> object(stdClass)#13 (3) { 
                  ["url"]=> string(79) "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/ded954f8e68911e2adc122000a1f9ace_5.jpg" 
                  ["width"]=> int(150) 
                  ["height"]=> int(150) 
              } 
              ["standard_resolution"]=> object(stdClass)#14 (3) { 
                  ["url"]=> string(79) "http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/ded954f8e68911e2adc122000a1f9ace_7.jpg" 
                  ["width"]=> int(612) 
                  ["height"]=> int(612) 
              } 
          } 
          ["users_in_photo"]=> array(0) { } 
          ["caption"]=> object(stdClass)#15 (4) { 
              ["created_time"]=> string(10) "1373149155" 
              ["text"]=> string(34) "#Mastering #TYGN #TRNCFRMCN #Remix" 
              ["from"]=> object(stdClass)#16 (4) { 
                  ["username"]=> string(12) "liebdich9vol" 
                  ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_444541508_75sq_1372633384.jpg" 
                  ["id"]=> string(9) "444541508" 
                  ["full_name"]=> string(11) "Ian Maybach" 
              } 
              ["id"]=> string(18) "494333402642093342" 
          } 
          ["user_has_liked"]=> bool(false) 
          ["id"]=> string(28) "494332600473064802_444541508" 
          ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#17 (6) { 
              ["username"]=> string(12) "liebdich9vol" 
              ["website"]=> string(0) "" 
              ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_444541508_75sq_1372633384.jpg"  
              ["full_name"]=> string(11) "Ian Maybach" 
              ["bio"]=> string(0) "" 
              ["id"]=> string(9) "444541508" 
          } 
      } 
      [1]=> object(stdClass)#18 (15) { 
          ["attribution"]=> NULL 
          ["tags"]=> array(3) { 
              [0]=> string(6) "studio" 
              [1]=> string(6) "garden" 
              [2]=> string(4) "view" 
          } 
          ["type"]=> string(5) "image" 
          ["location"]=> NULL 
          ["comments"]=> object(stdClass)#19 (2) { 
              ["count"]=> int(0) 
              ["data"]=> array(0) { } 
          } 
          ["filter"]=> string(7) "Toaster" 
          ["created_time"]=> string(10) "1372661045" 
          ["link"]=> string(34) "http://instagram.com/p/bNrZ-sl5Xp/" 
          ["likes"]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) { 
              ["count"]=> int(4) 
              ["data"]=> array(4) { 
                  [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { 
                      ["username"]=> string(9) "seanbabas" 
                      ["profile_picture"]=> string(76) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_30025104_75sq_1369077409.jpg" 
                      ["id"]=> string(8) "30025104" 
                      ["full_name"]=> string(10) "Sean Babas" 
                  } 
                  [1]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) { 
                      ["username"]=> string(12) "ginocolletti" 
                      ["profile_picture"]=> string(75) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_4634400_75sq_1364847565.jpg" 
                      ["id"]=> string(7) "4634400" 
                      ["full_name"]=> string(13) "Gino Colletti" 
                  } 
                  [2]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) { 
                      ["username"]=> string(13) "marygraceklee" 
                      ["profile_picture"]=> string(75) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3269702_75sq_1373251095.jpg" 
                      ["id"]=> string(7) "3269702" 
                      ["full_name"]=> string(13) "Marygrace Lee" 
                  } 
                  [3]=> object(stdClass)#24 (4) { 
                      ["username"]=> string(10) "cyonthefly" 
                      ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_225204950_75sq_1368426695.jpg" 
                      ["id"]=> string(9) "225204950" 
                      ["full_name"]=> string(21) "!CY ÊŽlÉŸÇÉ¥Ê‡uo âœˆ" 
                  } 
              } 
          } 
          ["images"]=> object(stdClass)#25 (3) { 
              ["low_resolution"]=> object(stdClass)#26 (3) { 
                  ["url"]=> string(79) "http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/9f5f0300e21911e2929322000a9e0719_6.jpg" 
                  ["width"]=> int(306) 
                  ["height"]=> int(306) 
              } 
              ["thumbnail"]=> object(stdClass)#27 (3) { 
                  ["url"]=> string(79) "http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/9f5f0300e21911e2929322000a9e0719_5.jpg" 
                  ["width"]=> int(150) 
                  ["height"]=> int(150) 
              } 
              ["standard_resolution"]=> object(stdClass)#28 (3) { 
                  ["url"]=> string(79) "http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/9f5f0300e21911e2929322000a9e0719_7.jpg" 
                  ["width"]=> int(612) 
                  ["height"]=> int(612) 
              } 
          } 
          ["users_in_photo"]=> array(0) { } 
          ["caption"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (4) { 
              ["created_time"]=> string(10) "1372900093" 
              ["text"]=> string(21) "#studio #view #garden" 
              ["from"]=> object(stdClass)#30 (4) { 
                  ["username"]=> string(12) "liebdich9vol" 
                  ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_444541508_75sq_1372633384.jpg" 
                  ["id"]=> string(9) "444541508" 
                  ["full_name"]=> string(11) "Ian Maybach" 
              } 
              ["id"]=> string(18) "492244118468531915" 
          } 
          ["user_has_liked"]=> bool(false) 
          ["id"]=> string(28) "490238835760272873_444541508" 
          ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#31 (6) { 
              ["username"]=> string(12) "liebdich9vol" 
              ["website"]=> string(0) "" 
              ["profile_picture"]=> string(77) "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_444541508_75sq_1372633384.jpg" 
              ["full_name"]=> string(11) "Ian Maybach" 
              ["bio"]=> string(0) "" 
              ["id"]=> string(9) "444541508" 
          } 
      } 
  }
```

My aim is to have only one picture on my site but navigation arrows to switch to the next one. How would that be achieved?

Comment: Use pre tags when displaying something from var_dump, it will display much more clearly and you will understand the structure easier.

Comment: As @DanyCaissy pointed out, use `<pre><?php print_r($data);?></pre>` instead of the `var_dump` and you will get the result in a much more readable way.  Thenyou will notice that you deal with arrays, so you need to use indeces to get to certain values.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by indeces?

Comment: Hint: Try to write a title for your Question that reads like a sentence, instead of putting many keywords together.

Answer (score 0):

To access infos from StdClass you can do this:

```
foreach($data->images as $i){
   $i->url;
}
```

You can force a casting to array too:

```
foreach($data->images as $i){
   $i = $i->toArray();
   $i['url'];
}
```

And you can get the json decode on array form:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true); //the second param true means, bring me it like array.
```

Comment: Thanks to you also. But I do not want to have all the images displayed, just one, so I cannot use the foreach command. :(

Comment: Ok, just don't use the foreach. But you'll need a key on your array to identify what image you need.

Comment: Thanks again, how can I get it there? Or am I just blind and too confused and they are there? :)

Comment: Its a product list right? What you have to know what product you 'll show? id? Name?

Comment: Do you mean the images @Guerra in the end when I am finished, or do you mean anything in the (now) array? What all the more confuses me, is how to tell PHP which image I need...but that's next step. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as per http://php.net/json_decode, you need to specify you want an associative array instead of an object from json_decode:

so use json decode like this

```
$result=json_decode($result, true);
```

Now you will get array and you can easily access data.

Comment: Thanks also. But how can I access the URLs now? How can I tell PHP I just want the standard resolution of one pic AND telling it with a click on a button to show the next one?